# maven and jboss modules

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm new to maven and jboss so I'm tring to get benefit of cooperation between them. I have a maven project in eclipse. The project has many dependencies that at runtime I want to provide as module from jboss, otherwise my EAR will be very big. I also use a nexus repo for my dependencies. My question is: is there a way to sync the dependencies I have at compile time in my pom.xml with modules on jboss? Is there a way to create jboss modules according to dependencies I declared in pom?

Probably I'm doing something wrong, because I'm loosing many time configuring jboos modules on the server and declaring dependencies in jboss-deplyment-structure.xml exactly  they are in pom files. What's Is the best practice?

Keep in mind that my first requirement is to not put all JAR in the EAR.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smartics JBoss Modules Maven Plugin creates the modules structure based on dependencies declared in your POM. Usually you have to fine tune the configuration to match your requirements.

This blog article may give you the basic idea to judge if this is the right approach to tackle your problem: [Modules Descriptor for smartics-jboss-modules-maven-plugin](http://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BLOG/2013/10/18/Maven+Plugin+to+generate+a+Modules+Directory+for+JBoss+AS+7)

You'll find more information on the plugin (and the project blog) on the [plugin's site](http://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/SJBMMP).

The project is available on GitHub.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of this plugin. :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'm sorry that the URL I provided did not work. I checked it now and I had no problem with HTTPS in my browsers. I changed them to HTTP to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

define module dependencies in pom.xml

maven-assembly-plugin:single collects dependency jars.

Generate module.xml with xslt:

maven-dependency-plugin:build-classpath creates a property containing the modules as one string. 
Now run maven-antrun-plugin with a build.xml containing JavaScript that splits the classpath string giving individual jars and adds them to ant properties, using a prefix. echoproperties writes these properties to an xml file giving the input for xslt.