# Map JBoss Modules to Maven pom.xml Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss7.x, dependency-management

I've got an artifact that I'm deploying to a JBoss environment with some optional (but stock AS7) modules configured.  I want to make sure that my "provided" dependencies as declared in my pom.xml, are in sync with the modules declared in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml.  Is there a standard mechanism or reference for doing this?  I'm not certain how/if the modules correlate to maven dependencies.

I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573009/maven-and-jboss-modules), but it dealt with going the other direction from maven dependency -> jboss module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aight, I think I've found a good approach.  JBoss does maintain a Maven BOM project [on gitHub](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-boms).  This will enumerate all dependencies associated with a particular AS/EAP version (you can cross-reference the BOM with the app server spec [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673)).  To use this, just add the BOM to your project like so:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-eap</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now you can be certain that you're compiling/linking against a set of dependencies that is compatible with your application server.  aaaah - that feels better!