# How to use smartics-jboss-modules maven plugin in maven project

Tags: maven, auto-generate, jboss-modules

We can create module.xml manually and keep it in modules folder of Jboss. But to autogenerate it, there is a plugin called smartics-jboss-modules-maven-plugin. Has anyone implemented it in maven project. My requirement is to generate module.xml and module from maven project and automatically add it to jboss modules folder. I need to know the exact steps to implement it in my project.

Comment: Check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573009/maven-and-jboss-modules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maven and jboss modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573009/maven-and-jboss-modules)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have already gone through it and the article is missing some steps. It would be great if you can help me with steps required to configure it in maven project

Answer (score 0):

[image]

and inside that particular folder make sure you create a file that complies with the following model

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
```

As documented in here:

https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/SJBMMP/The+smartics+JBoss+Modules+XSD